# tar: Using `--one-top-level` when input is piped in

Tags: bash, tar

I'm trying to download a tar (works) and immediately unpack it to a subdirectory (ideally named the same as the archive). I thought following code should work but it attempts to write the write unpacked files to STDOUT and fails.

```bsh
wget -O - https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~zabokrtsky/courses/npfl104/data/classification/artificial_objects.tgz | tar -xvz --one-top-level
```

Results in (very cryptic failure):

```
...
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’
...
Cannot write to ‘-’ (Success).
```

Not specifying `--one-top-level` fixes the issue but then the files inside just get extracted to current folder, as expected.

Doing it in two separate commands: downloading it first and then unpacking with intermediate file works, again as expected.

```bsh
wget https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~zabokrtsky/courses/npfl104/data/classification/artificial_objects.tgz
tar -xvz --one-top-level -f artificial_objects.tgz
```

I know that I could create a subfolder and change tar's output directory using -C but I'd rather understand why my approach doesn't work.

TAR v2016

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ideally named the same as the archive

It's true [`man 1 tar`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) says

> `--one-top-level[=DIR]`
>   Extract all files into `DIR`, or, if used without argument, into a subdirectory named by the base name of the archive (minus standard compression suffixes recognizable by `--auto-compress`).

The problem is `tar` in your pipe cannot know the name of the archive; only `wget` knows it. The message `Cannot write to ‘-’ (Success)` is cryptic to me, *as if the tool got confused*. In my tests the exit status is `2`, this contradicts the alleged "success". Maybe `tar` should be improved in handling this case.

Anyway, `tar` doesn't know the name of the archive. It will work if you provide `DIR`:

```
wget -O - https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/~zabokrtsky/courses/npfl104/data/classification/artificial_objects.tgz \
| tar -xvz --one-top-level=artificial_objects
```

It may or may not be `artificial_objects`, it's totally up to you. The tool will create the directory, if needed.

---

Based on

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.29
…
```